# Dash: Creating a dropdown per column, instead of a dropdown per table

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
cat_id  author  year    publisher   country value (dollars)
name1   kunga   1998    D and D Australia   10
name2   siba    2001    D and D UK  20
name3   siba    2001    D and D US  20
name3   shevara 2001    D and D UK  10
name3   dougherty   1992    D and D Australia   20
name4   ken 2011    S and K Australia   10
```

The aim, to produce a Multi-Select Dropdown menu PER COLUMN, not of all columns (because the per-column filter that i currently do is not sufficient, I need to be able to filter by multiple items per column in one go).

Using the above example, this would add a cell just under cat_id with name1,2,3,4; author would have a dropdown with kunga, siba, shevara and dougherty; year would have a dropdown with 1992,1998,2001,2011 etc.

I wrote the below code:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
df = pd.read_excel('dash_test_doc.xlsx')


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Input(
            id='adding-rows-name',
            placeholder='Enter a column name...',
            value='',
            style={'padding': 10},),html.Button('Add Column', id='adding-rows-button', n_clicks=0)], style={'height': 50}),

#Need to move this to being within each column?
        html.Label('Multi-Select Dropdown'),
            dcc.Dropdown(options=[{'label':i,'value':i} for i in df.columns],
            value = [i for i in df.columns],
            multi=True),


        dash_table.DataTable(
         id='adding-rows-table',
         columns=[{"name": i, "id": i,"deletable":True} for i in df.columns],
#        column_conditional_dropdowns=[{'id':i,'dropdowns':df[i]} for i in df.columns],
         data = df.to_dict('rows'),
         editable=True,
         filtering=True,
         sorting=True,
         sorting_type="multi",
         row_selectable="multi",
         row_deletable=True,
         selected_rows=[],
         pagination_mode="fe",
         style_cell_conditional=[
         {
             'if': {'row_index': 'odd'},
             'backgroundColor': 'rgb(230, 255, 230)'
         }
     ] + [
         {
             'if': {'column_id': c},
             'textAlign': 'left'
        } for c in ['Date', 'Region']
    ],
    style_header={
        'backgroundColor': 'white',
        'fontWeight': 'bold'
    }
    ),



    html.Button('Add Row', id='editing-rows-button', n_clicks=0),
    dcc.Graph(id='adding-rows-graph')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('adding-rows-table', 'data'),
    [Input('editing-rows-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('adding-rows-table', 'data'),
     State('adding-rows-table', 'columns')])
def add_row(n_clicks, rows, columns):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        rows.append({c['id']: '' for c in columns})
    return rows


@app.callback(
    Output('adding-rows-table', 'columns'),
    [Input('adding-rows-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('adding-rows-name', 'value'),
     State('adding-rows-table', 'columns')])
def update_columns(n_clicks, value, existing_columns):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        existing_columns.append({
            'id': value, 'name': value,
            'editable_name': True, 'deletable': True
        })
    return existing_columns


@app.callback(
    Output('adding-rows-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('adding-rows-table', 'data'),
     Input('adding-rows-table', 'columns')])
def display_output(rows, columns):
    return {
        'data': [{
            'type': 'heatmap',
            'z': [[row.get(c['id'], None) for c in columns] for row in rows],
            'x': [c['name'] for c in columns]
        }]
    }



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

There are two specific issues with this method:

1. The dropdown is being done at the table level, not the per-column level.
2. I want to then filter the table to only display what is in the dropdown bar, which is currently not being done.

I know that the parts of the code that are the issue are:

```
#Need to move this to being within each column?
        html.Label('Multi-Select Dropdown'),
            dcc.Dropdown(options=[{'label':i,'value':i} for i in df.columns],
            value = [i for i in df.columns],
            multi=True),
```

and that there is no callback, but I'm new to dash, and I'm struggling to understand what specifically I should do. If someone could show me how to fix these two issues in this code, I would appreciate it.

As a side note/disclaimer, I had originally asked this question as part of a much bigger question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871311/dash-plotly-create-a-dropdown-menu-dynamically-selection-of-multiple-rows-ta/55880965#55880965), but I have realised that I need to make my questions more code-specific, and more specific in general, so I'm going to work through each issue individually.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Kela, for making this question a little more specific. This still a good size bite, so I'll see if I can help with all of it.

First thing is you need to change the column defintion in the table to have `'presentation': 'dropdown'` in the dictionary for each column you want to show up as a dropdown. The current dropdown isn't working inside the table because you've used the `dcc.Dropdown` component, which is a separate component from the table. You'll need to use `column_static_dropdown` or `column_conditional_dropdowns` (which I see you've commented out) if you want them to work inside the table.

I'm not sure that the dropdowns inside the table can be used as part of a callback, though. I tried to hook one up, and the ID of the dropdown was not recognized as part of the layout. To do what you want would - I think - require setting up multiple dropdowns using `dcc.Dropdown` and hooking those values up as input to the callback that updates the table's `data` prop.

Here is a little example that I've confirmed works, with some limitations:

```py
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(30).reshape(5, 6))

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Input(
            id='adding-rows-name',
            placeholder='Enter a column name...',
            value='',
            style={'padding': 10}, ),
        html.Button('Add Column', id='adding-rows-button', n_clicks=0)], style={'height': 50}),

    # Need to move this to being within each column?
    html.Label('Multi-Select Dropdown'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='test-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df[0]],
        value=[i for i in df[0]],
        multi=True),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='adding-rows-table',
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True} for i in df.columns],
        data=df.to_dict('rows'),
        editable=True,
        filtering=True,
        sorting=True,
        sorting_type="multi",
        row_selectable="multi",
        row_deletable=True,
        selected_rows=[],
        pagination_mode="fe",
        style_cell_conditional=[
               {
                   'if': {'row_index': 'odd'},
                   'backgroundColor': 'rgb(230, 255, 230)'
               }
           ] + [
               {
                   'if': {'column_id': c},
                   'textAlign': 'left'
               } for c in ['Date', 'Region']
           ],
        style_header={
            'backgroundColor': 'white',
            'fontWeight': 'bold'
        }
    ),

    html.Button('Add Row', id='editing-rows-button', n_clicks=0),
    dcc.Graph(id='adding-rows-graph'),
])


@app.callback(
    Output('adding-rows-table', 'data'),
    [Input('editing-rows-button', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('test-dropdown', 'value')],
    [State('adding-rows-table', 'data'),
     State('adding-rows-table', 'columns')])
def add_row(n_clicks, dropdown_value, rows, columns):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        rows.append({c['id']: '' for c in columns})

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rows)

    try:
        df_filtered = df[df['0'].isin(dropdown_value)]
    except TypeError:
        df_filtered = df[df['0'].eq(dropdown_value)]

    return df_filtered.to_dict(orient='records')
```

There is only one dropdown right now, and it works with the values in the first column. You would need to add more, and it would get complicated quickly. You could probably style the dropdowns so they're more clearly associated with the related columns .

There is also the problem of what to do with rows once you've filtered them out. The callback pulls in the `State` `data` from the table but, if a row was filtered out, then it's not in the state and can't be added back in by making that selection in the dropdown again. You would need a different way to handle storing the data for the table so that rows aren't erased this way.